# Splitting dataframe on number of rows

Tags: r, dataframe, split

I want to split my dataframe based on a certain number of rows to be included in each split and then write each split out as a separate .csv file.

```
library(tidyverse)
n = 10000 #number of groups

split <- correlation %>% group_by(row.names() %/% n) %>% group_walk(~ write_csv(.x, paste0("file_", .y, ".csv")))
```

I am using the above mentioned code to split my data, however the output .csv files lack rownames information and I would like for it to have the rownames. Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: I would use `tibble::rownames_to_column()` and just avoid the rownames.

Answer (score 0):

Try using write.csv instead and including row.names = TRUE as an extra argument, i.e.

```r
group_walk(~write.csv(.x, paste0("file_", .y, ".csv"), row.names=TRUE))
```